# Can't pause google web activity and applications

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

I try to to pause google web activity and applications by turning off the relevant switch.

But when I press 'Pause' at the message which pops up after I turned off the switch then it does not move forward and so I have to press inevitable cancel.

How can I finally pause this?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved it.

The problem was that I was translating at English the original webpage which was at my native language.

For some reason, it was not pausing on the translated webpage but when I did it on the original one then it was turned off.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for sharing the solution.